# Add Thousand separator to any number even if it contains special characters

Tags: php, regex, number-formatting, magento-1.9

I have a site in Norwegian price format, so the product price displays like `1000,-`.

It is a Magento based site, version ce-1.9.2.1.

Now I want to add thousand separator (most probably spaces but could be any character) to that price maintaining its format by using `number_format` function or regex, whichever maintains integrity best (like `1 000,-` , `1 000 000,-` etc.).

Anybody having any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lookarounds in `preg_replace` you can do this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\..*$(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/', ' ', $str);
```

`\..*$(*SKIP)(*F)` will ignore/skip part after `DOT` for this conversion.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aF5aP6/3)

Comment: your regex is almost working, but it ignores first occurrence of '.' decimal separator, can you update it to not put thousand separator after it finds '.' ?

Comment: So an example would input be: `1000123.45678` and you want `1 000 123.45678` as output?

Comment: Exactly, I don't want thousand separator to appear after decimal separator as it is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks man great one liner answer, you're a life saver. +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to my 5 minutes of research on the google, [the formal currency format for Norwegian Krone](http://www.thefinancials.com/Default.aspx?SubSectionID=curformat) are `#.###,##`.

The only difference between this format and the one that you propose, is that the Krone separator is "" instead of "`.`", and the special value of "`,00`" øre is replaced with "`,-`".

Based on that observation, I would simply run the following code, given a properly formatted value in the formal definition:

```
// expects "1.234,00" returns "1 234,-"
//     "1.234.567,00" ==> "1 234 567,-"
//              5,50  ==>          5,50
function kroneDisplayFormat($formalFormat) {
    $intermediate = str_replace(".", " "); // replace . separator with ' ' (space)
    if( endsWith( $intermediate, ",00")) {
       // special display case ",00" ==> ",-"
       $final = str_replace(",00", ",-");
    } else {
       $final = $intermediate
    }
    return $final
}
```